# When Building VSCode From Source, How to Enable the Experimental Settings Sync?

Tags: synchronization, visual-studio-code, microsoft-account

VSCode v1.43 has experimental support for settings sync using Microsoft account: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync

The "Turn on Sync..." option exists in Insiders, but not when building VSCode from source.

I found the reason is missing configuration in `product.json`.

Is there any way to enable settings sync in this mode? This is mandatory because I need to debug some code of this feature.